# Move span to the center of footer div

Tags: html, css

I have next HTML code, I want to put copyright span to the center of footer but I am can just put them to the top center. What I need to change in my CSS ?

```
<div class="main">   
    <div class="footer">
        <span class="copyright">some text block</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and next CSS

```
.main { width: 100%; height:1563px;  background:url(../images/1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat ; overflow:hidden; position:relative;min-height:100%; }
.footer {position:absolute;  bottom:0;  width:100%;  text-align:center;   height:60px; background-color: #CDCBB8}
.copyright { font-family:"Myriad Pro", sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#999; display: inline-block;    vertical-align: middle; line-height: normal; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `line-height:60px` for copyright:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ42D/)

```
.copyright { 
font-family:"Myriad Pro", sans-serif; 
font-size:14px; color:#999; 
display: inline-block;    
vertical-align: middle; 
line-height: 60px;  /* as the height of container  */
}
```

or set `line-height:60px` to the continer like this:

```
.footer {
position:absolute;  
bottom:0;  width:100%;  
text-align:center;   
height:60px;
line-height:60px;  /*  as the height  */
background-color: #CDCBB8
}
```

***note:** if you have more than one line in your copyright it is better that you set `line-height:60px` to the container and set `line-height:1;` to the copyright. 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ42D/1/)*

Answer (score 1):

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/dfW66/

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    height:1563px;
    background:url(../images/1.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #CDCBB8
}
.copyright {
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#999;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Set line-height to 60px.

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align:middle` can put into action by changing `display` properties of `.footer` and `.copyright` to `table` and `table-cell`, like this:

```
.footer{
 display:table;
}
.copyright{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Then your `vertical-align:middle` will move the copyright text to vertically middle.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
.footer{display:table;}
.copyright{display:table-cell;}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Tz3mx/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the text you want to center you can do:

```
text-align: center;
```

If you want to center the whole div give it a width and call

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

on it.